# If $7|(100a+b)$ prove $7|(2a+b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

It looks pretty easy but I can't see a way out of this problem.

If $7|100a+b$, prove $7|2a+b$, $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: If $7\mid 100a+b$ does $7\mid 100a+b-7$?  How about $100a+b-7a$?  How about...

Comment: $100 = (14*7+2)$

Comment: If $7\mid 100a+b$, then $7\mid (100a+b)-7\cdot 14a$.

Comment: **HInt** $\ 100\equiv 2\pmod 7.\ $ Are you familiar with congruences / modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 4):

We have that

$$100a+b\equiv 0 \mod 7$$

$$\implies 100a-7*14a+b\equiv 0 \mod 7$$

$$\implies 2a+b\equiv 0 \mod 7$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $7|(100a+b)$ and also $7|7a$.

Hence $7|(14\times 7a) \implies 7|98a$.

Thus, we can say that $\boxed {7|(100a+b)-98a \implies 7|(2a+b)}$.

Comment: The phrase "assuming $a$ is nonzero" is unnecessary.  Everything divides zero just as one divides everything.  $x\mid y$ iff $y=xk$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.  In particular $k$ can be zero, thus since $0=x\cdot 0$ we have $x\mid 0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Corrected that part.